# Poor printing results with Hoin POS-58 thermal printer

Tags: printing, thermal-printer

Im using a thermal printer (Hoin POS-58) to print receipts but i dont like the final result due to ugly font styles.

Im setting font-family and font-size in css print media query but as i told you the results are poor.

However, I can see how the selftest page font are much more pretty.

Do you know what font is "Font-A" or how can I set a propper font or configure printer to print the same way than in selftest page?

Im using Ubuntu 18.04 and google chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thermal receipt printer can print beautifully at the lowest cost when requesting printing of text with character code.

In that case, the font data held by the printer is used, and it has only a few types of fonts with different character sizes (number of dots).

The font does not have a name like that given on a PC, etc., and is usually named Font-A/Font-B/Font-C.

However, there is no standard for font content and it depends on the vendor and model.

Also, unlike PC fonts, it is not possible to specify the size in 1-point units, and the decoration of characters can only be specified within a poor range.

---

On the other hand, the print result you got is probably that the application and the print driver have expanded the print content into a bit image and requested the printer to print it as a bit image.

The method of developing and printing on a bit image can produce poor results, such as yours, or you can obtain precise results, such as photographs.

It depends on how beautiful and precise the bit image can be created when creating print data.

---

There are two directions you can do.

One is to improve the beauty and fineness of the bit image data for printing to be created while keeping the current method.

The other is to stop creating print data as a bit image, to request printing by text in character code, and print contents and printer by the control code supported by the printer (usually ESC / POS original extension). Is to switch to control.

In this case, you will need to change everything from the printer's hardware mode settings to the printer driver to the application's control method.